# Is "some" function part of generic SQL?

Tags: sql, function

I can use "some()" function at Oracle, Potsgresql and Sql Server. But is it a generic SQL function or is part of some extensions?

Comment: Did you mean `SOME` comparison condition (or operator)?

Comment: If so it's part of ANSI SQL 92 and I believe most of RDBMSes support it. And `SOME` and `ANY` are synonyms.

Answer (score 4):

`some` is an alias for `ANY` none of them being an "function" but a condition (or operator).

They are somewhat similar to the `IN` (and `ALL`) operator, only that they don't operator on the full set of the related sub-query, but only on "*some*" (or "*any*) of the rows.

Here is the relevant part in the PostgreSQL manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18025

Here is the relevant part of the Oracle manual:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions002.htm#CJAGAABC

And here is the relevant part of the SQL Server manual:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175064%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

(Partial) quote from the ANSI SQL 2006 standard:

```
<quantified comparison predicate>

<quantified comparison predicate> ::=
   <row value predicand> <quantified comparison predicate part 2>

<quantified comparison predicate part 2> ::=
   <comp op> <quantifier> <table subquery>

<quantifier> ::=
  <all>
  | <some>

<all> ::=
   ALL

<some> ::=
  SOME
  | ANY
```

Comment: +1, but isn't the OP asking if they are part of a "standard sql"?  Op says they can already use them in Oracle, Potsgresql and Sql Server.

Comment: do you have a link to that?

Answer (score 1):

Queries with operator SOME() and ANY() works in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

It is part of ISO/IEC 9075:1992, also known as ANSI SQL 92 standard. See "8.7 <quantified comparison predicate>" at [sql-1992 document](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).